# Download a text file from a URL and use the data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'd like to download the data from a URL (which is just a text file), and then be able to use the data in JavaScript, ideally adding each line of the text file to an element of an array.

I've looked around for a simple way to do this but can't seem find anything appropriate.

Comment: Is the url of a local file: `file://...`?

Comment: Just use AJAX. As long as it's not disobeying cross allow origin policy and it's online, it should work.

Comment: Why don't you provide some code of what you have deemed insufficient?

Comment: You want [XMLHttpRequest](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp).  Docs there (and an example) are pretty clear but let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for AJAX! It's a API which allows you to submit a request in JavaScript. An easy library to help you get started is [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/).

Say you want to fetch the contents of example.com/file.txt and display it in an alert:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://example.com/file.txt",
}).done(function(r) {
    alert(r);
});
```

AJAX is great because the request is asynchronous, meaning it doesn't have to slow down the loading of the rest of your page: it runs alongside your other code.

Further [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) on jQuery AJAX.